# Turn off in-app purchases on xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to test my app on an iPad / iPhone.

I've not registered for the developer program yet. I do have an `appleId`, was waiting until the app was more or less ready before I enrolled in the program.

Anyway, when I try to run the app I just get told that

```
The 'In-App Purchase' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit 
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll
```

I know there is some setting somewhere for me to turn off in-app purchases, just not sure where it is? I've scoured most of the settings pages, run searched etc. and just cant seem to get past this?

edit: heres my capabilities tab in my xcode project settings.

[image: xcode project settings]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For anyone who's coming across the same problem, this issue arises when you 1) previously had a developer account which expired and 2) you had in-app purchases enabled.

The solution is to go to click on the main project root in the left side panel which should reveal the project properties. Scroll to the bottom and there is a Linked Frameworks and Libraries. Remove the StoreKit.framework, go to Signing, disable the 'Automatically manage signing' option and enable it again. If needed, set your Team to 'None' and set it back to your Personal Development Team, which should trigger the automatic provisioning mechanism.

Comment: That exactly what I need, my account expired a few month ago.

Comment: @zephinzer thanks for your detailed description of how to get this done!

Comment: Any update on this for Xcode 11, which doesn't match the instructions given here?

Comment: It amazes me that the richest software companies in the world can't this kind of thing fixed in a timely fashion. I mean, it's not like your third-party developers are what make your platform compelling, aye, Apple?

Answer (score 10):

If nothing helps, you can edit YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and remove all strings containing `StoreKit` and

```
com.apple.InAppPurchase = {
    enabled = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the provisioning profile in the project settings!

It was set to auto, changed it a provisioning profile containing my app name, all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the toggle in the Capabilities section and you should be good to go!

Comment: thanks for the answer but I didn't have the toggle, thats the weird bit! It seems to have been an issue with the provisioning profile...

Comment: Uncheck 'Automatically manage signing'. So that you will see the in-app purchases capability. Toggle it and then enable 'Automatically manage signing' option.

Answer (score -1):

You question isn't clear enough.

Check the image below to turn off In-App Purchase.

[image]

Comment: apologies if my question isn't clear enough. I figured a while back it was just going to be a simple setting, but I don't have the options you have in your screen, I've updated my question with a screenshot of my capabilities tab.